# Can I use 'LINES STARTING BY' and 'LINES TERMINATED BY' on the same query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

I'm working on a procedure that copies some data into a text file using two prepared statements (`@aux1` and `@aux2`). Then the table where the information is copied, get's all of it's rows deleted.

The issue is that when I execute the procedure using `call copyIntoFile()` I get an error.

**PROCEDURE**

```
delimiter !!
drop procedure if exists copyIntoFile !!
create procedure copyIntoFile()

begin
    declare path varchar(255);
    set path = concat("'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Uploads/", curdate(), ".txt'");

    set @aux1 = concat("select * from movie_modification where modified = true into outfile ", path, 
                        " fields terminated by ';' lines starting by 'Edit: ' lines terminated by '\n';");
    prepare stmt1 from @aux1;
    execute stmt1;
    deallocate prepare stmt1;

    set @aux2 = concat("select * from movie_modification where modified = false into outfile ", path, 
                        " fields terminated by ';' lines starting by 'New: ' lines terminated by '\n';");
    prepare stmt2 from @aux2;
    execute stmt2;
    deallocate prepare stmt2;

    delete from movie_modification;
end !!
delimiter ;
```

**ERROR** (When executing the procedure)

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'lines terminated by ' '' at line 1

As you can see, the error occurs near `lines terminated by` (at line 1). So now I'm wondering if I can use `lines terminated by` after `lines starting by` or if just one of this statements is accepted in each query.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to replace this:

```
select ...
into outfile ...
fields terminated by ';' lines starting by 'Edit: ' lines terminated by '\n'
```

With:

```
select ...
into outfile ...
fields terminated by ';' lines starting by 'Edit: ' terminated by '\n'
```

That is: the `lines` keyword should not be repeated.